# Browser forcing https when http is entered on localhost

Tags: php, apache, https

I have a local PHP development environment set up on my windows box. I am using WAMP for the php/apache install.

When I navigate to my php app (http://localhost:8040) for some reason the browser replaces http with https. This causes me to be unable to go to my site on localhost since https is not enabled for the site or port 8040.

It used to not do this and behave normally. Then all of a sudden the browser (or perhaps local server) started forcing https.

Is there anything I can do to stop this behavior or debug why it is happening?

Comment: Without configuration details or even debugging what part is causing the redirect this question is way too broad.

Comment: Which configs should I post to help fix this mystery?

Comment: Well, let's start with things you recently changed or updated. Apache is configured via httpd.conf and .htaccess files. Try cleaning out the www-directory by moving everything to a temporary folder somewhere and see if the behaviour persists. Tell us if the redirect is temporary or permanent.